# video replay on slider

Tags: video.js, anythingslider

video.js Hello. I'm trying to have a video autoplay when slider starts. That part is working. Problem occurs though when it loops through and comes back to the video, the video will not replay. I've tried to figure it out with a loop="true" but if I do that it just plays video over and over and then slider doesn't work. Any advice? Thanks! (I can add my code if needed)

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>AnythingSlider Video Demo</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="demos/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="demos/images/apple-touch-icon.png">

<!-- jQuery (required) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- Demo stuff -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="demos/css/page.css">

<!-- Anything Slider optional plugins, but needed so the embeded video controls will work in IE -->
<!-- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js -->
<script src="js/swfobject.js"></script>

<!-- Anything Slider -->
<link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/anythingslider.css">
<script src="js/jquery.anythingslider.js"></script>

<!-- AnythingSlider video extension; optional, but needed to control video pause/play -->
<script src="js/jquery.anythingslider.video.js"></script>

<script>
// DOM Ready
$(function(){
$('#slider')
.anythingSlider({
resizeContents      : true,
autoPlay            : true,
addWmodeToObject    : 'opaque',
buildStartStop: false,  
navigationFormatter : function(index, panel){ //  Format navigation labels with text
return [][index - 1];

}
})


// Initialize video extension

// see https://developers.google.com/youtube   /player_parameters?hl=en#Parameters for a list of parameters

.anythingSliderVideo({
startPanel          : 1,
// video id prefix; suffix from    
$.fn.anythingSliderVideo.videoIndex
videoId : 'asvideo',
// auto load YouTube api script
youtubeAutoLoad : false,
wmode: 'transparent&autoplay=1', // (hack) add autoplay code here
// see: https://developers.google.com/youtube    /player_parameters#Parameters
youtubeParams: {
modestbranding : 1,
iv_load_policy : 3,    
fs : 1  
}
});
});
</script>
<script src="video.js"></script>

<!-- Unless using the CDN hosted version, update the URL to the Flash SWF -->

<script>
videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
</script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- START AnythingSlider -->
<ul id="slider">    

<!-- HTML5 Video -->
<li class="panel5">
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay preload="auto" autoplay="true" width="640" height="264"
poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
data-setup="{}">
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
<track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English">    
</track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
</video>
</li>
 <li><img src="demos/images/slide-civil-1.jpg" alt=""></li>

<li><img src="demos/images/slide-env-1.jpg" alt=""></li>

<li><img src="demos/images/slide-civil-2.jpg" alt=""></li>

<li><img src="demos/images/slide-env-2.jpg" alt=""></li>

</ul> <!-- END AnythingSlider -->

<br>

</div>

<br>
```

Comment: Add the code please as it will be a lot easier to help you with it.

Comment: Add it to your question, no in comments. Edit your question and copy the code and format it : http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Any ideas?

Comment: No sorry, I was reviewing your question when I added my comments. I hoped that adding the code would have people with the knowledge to help you give you a answer as it is easier for those with the knowledge to answer you with it. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I think what I'm trying to do isn't common practice but we're wanting it for digital signage. I do believe there is a way to do it but I haven't figured it out yet. I've tried lots of things, though! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the autoplay parameter of the `<video>` tag to "autoplay" instead of true. This worked for me using Anything Slider.